# How to catch text till paranthesis in Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a concatenated text that I want to split using Regex. Luckily there is a pattern. The pattern is structured this way: (seconds) some text (seconds) some other text (seconds) some other text

> (1-4) Agent: THANK YOU FOR CALLING XCOMPANY MY NAME IS DEVIN  HOW CAN
> I HELP YOU (5-22) Customer: HI KEVIN I TRANSFERRED OVER TO YOU ... (24-29) Agent: OK  AY (662-662) Customer: THANK YOU
> TOO (663-664) Agent: THANKS  BYE NOW (664-664) Customer: BYE

I want to split each block so output should be like this.

```
(1-4) Agent: THANK YOU FOR CALLING XCOMPANY MY NAME IS DEVIN  HOW CAN I HELP YOU 
(5-22) Customer: HI KEVIN I TRANSFERRED OVER TO YOU ... ABOUT THAT BILL 
(24-29) Agent: OK  AY
```

So far I was able to create this `\(\d*-\d*\)\s*\w*:\s*`, but this catches *(1-4) Agent:* I can't figure out the rest, I tried many things.

Here is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JoAzQj/1) link, showing where I am stuck.

Comment: Try `\(\d*-\d*\)\s*\w*:[^(]*` which catches everything after the colon that is not an open parenthesis.

Comment: Hey Michael, It worked. Can you send your suggestion as post and I can mark as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
\(\d*-\d*\)\s*\w*:[^(]*
```

you can catch everything after the colon that is not an open parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

In the pattern that you have tried, the digits between parenthesis are optional due to the `*`, and the `\w*:\s*` does not match beyond optional word characters `:` and optional whitespace chars.

---

You can use:

```
\(\d+-\d+\).*?(?=\(\d+-\d+\)|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(\d+-\d+\)` match `(`, 1+ digits `-` 1+ digits and `)`
- `.*?` Match any character, as few as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `\(\d+-\d+\)` The digit pattern between parenthesis
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string (For the last occurrence)
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ydmK4/1)

Example code

```
import re

pattern = r"\(\d+-\d+\).*?(?=\(\d+-\d+\)|$)"

s = "(1-4) Agent: THANK YOU FOR CALLING XCOMPANY MY NAME IS DEVIN HOW CAN I HELP YOU (5-22) Customer: HI KEVIN I TRANSFERRED OVER TO YOU ... (24-29) Agent: OK AY (662-662) Customer: THANK YOU TOO (663-664) Agent: THANKS BYE NOW (664-664) Customer: BYE"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[
'(1-4) Agent: THANK YOU FOR CALLING XCOMPANY MY NAME IS DEVIN HOW CAN I HELP YOU ',
'(5-22) Customer: HI KEVIN I TRANSFERRED OVER TO YOU ... ',
'(24-29) Agent: OK AY ',
'(662-662) Customer: THANK YOU TOO ',
'(663-664) Agent: THANKS BYE NOW ', '(664-664) Customer: BYE'
]
```

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird for this excellent explanation. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try Match groups

```
(\(\d*-\d*\)\s*\w+:[\s?\w]+[^(]){1}
```

I'm not much of a regex pro but I do try. Let me know if it helped :D

Comment: What's the point of the `{1}`?

Comment: It kinda worked. Thanks. But just wanted to let you know it fails when there are apostrophes. I am looking at my whole test text. Example: 

> `(80-90) Customer: YEAH THAT'` s alright <   (then it stops). There are like 10% with apostrophes. But, thanks though. It could be improved.